# Add new column based on values of another column from a dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
foo_dt = pd.DataFrame({'var_1': ['filter coffee', 'american cheesecake', 'espresso coffee', 'latte tea'],
                   'var_2': ['coffee', 'coffee black', 'tea', 'strawberry cheesecake']})
```

and the following dictionary:

```
foo_colors = {'coffee': 'brown', 'cheesecake': 'white', 'tea': 'green'}
```

I want to add two columns in `foo_dt` (`color_var_1` and `color_var_2`), the values of which will be the respective `value` of the `foo_colors` dictionary which corresponds to the `key` depending if the `key` is `in` the value of the column `var_1` or `var_2` respectively.

**EDIT**

In other words, for every key in `foo_colors` , check where "it is contained" in both columns `var_1` & `var_2`, and then give as value of the respective column (`color_var_1` & `color_var_2`) the respective value of the dictionary

My resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
           var_1                     var_2                  color_var_1   color_var_2
0          filter coffee             coffee                 brown         brown
1          american cheesecake       coffee black           white         brown
2          espresso coffee           tea                    brown         green
3          latte tea                 strawberry cheesecake  green         white
```

Any idea how can I do this ?

Comment: @jezrael Sorry about that. I edited. Is it more clear now ?

Comment: For me yes, I think super question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get first matched substring created by join by `|` for regex `or` of keys in dict with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) by dict:

```
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in foo_colors)

for c in ['var_1','var_2']:
    foo_dt[f'color_{c}'] = foo_dt[c].str.extract(f'({pat})', expand=False).map(foo_colors)
print(foo_dt)
                 var_1                  var_2 color_var_1 color_var_2
0        filter coffee                 coffee       brown       brown
1  american cheesecake           coffee black       white       brown
2      espresso coffee                    tea       brown       green
3            latte tea  strawberry cheesecake       green       white
```